# Uploading image in S3 via REST API

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, forms, amazon-s3, curl

So I have a html form which accepts the image from user.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="call-api.php">
  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="image" class="btn btn-default">
  <input type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

Then the image is sent to AWS API Gateway which uses S3 as proxy and uploads the image in S3. I am using PHP curl to make REST API call:

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {
    //create a handler for curl function 
    $curl = curl_init(); //initialzie cURL session

    //The CURLFile class 
    $cfile = new CURLFile($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['type'], $_FILES['image']['name']);

    //use array to post data to different server or within localhost 
    $data = array("myimage" => $cfile);


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/test57827/'.$_FILES['image']['name']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    //assign  execute curl to a response variable
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
?>
```

The problem with this code is that it uploads a file in S3 with name `$_FILES['image']['name']` but that file is not an image because After downloading that file from S3, i cant open it in normal image previewer program and get error "file format is not recognised"

But when i use curl command from terminal to call my api then the image gets uploaded in S3 because when i download it from S3 , i can open it in normal image previewer program.

```
curl --request POST -H "Content-Type: */*"  --data-binary "@image.png"  https://xxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/test57827/myfile.jpeg
```

I have tried multiple versions of my php code but none of them is able to upload the image in correct way. I dont want to use AWS SDK. Any guidance with php curl will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it is untested, but maybe you need a content-Type for POST, so that the API can process the request's data correctly:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [ 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' ]);
```

**EDIT:**
I found a tutorial which show work: https://ryansechrest.com/2012/07/send-and-receive-binary-files-using-php-and-curl/ Maybe that's the way to go.

Comment: it didnt work. still same issue.